# Как переустановить VS 2015 с диска H на диск C?

Tags: visual-studio

Здравствуйте. Требуется установить VS2015 на диск C. В прошлом она стояла на диске H, я ее оттуда удалил. Теперь при установке он намертво решил, что надо снова ставить на диск H, и не позволяет мне изменить выбор. Как это исправить?